# PSQL / SQL: Is it possible to further optimize this query with requiring write access to the database?

Tags: sql, postgresql, psql

I have a query here that uses four subqueries inside a single CTE, and each subquery is scanning every row of another CTE for each row in itself. I would think that this is very inefficient.

Are there any SQL optimizations that I can implement now that the proof of concept is finished?
I don't have write access to the database, so optimizations would be required within the select clause.

```
WITH datetable AS (
    SELECT generate_series(
        DATE_TRUNC('week', (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM org_accounts.deleted_users)),
        DATE_TRUNC('week', now()),
        '1 week'::INTERVAL
    )::DATE AS week_start
), all_users AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        registered_at,
        NULL AS deleted_at
    FROM org_accounts.users
    WHERE status = 'active'
        AND org_accounts.__user_is_qa(id) <> 'Y'
        AND email NOT LIKE '%@org%'
    
    UNION ALL
    
    SELECT
        id,
        created_at AS registered_at,
        deleted_at
    FROM org_accounts.deleted_users
    WHERE deleter_id = id
        AND email NOT LIKE '%@org%'
), weekly_activity AS (
    SELECT
        DATE_TRUNC('week', date)::DATE AS week_start,
        COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) AS weekly_active_users
    FROM (
      SELECT user_id, date
      FROM org_storage_extra.stats_user_daily_counters 
      WHERE type in ('created_file', 'created_folder', 'created_secure_fetch')
      
      UNION ALL
      
      SELECT user_id, date
      FROM ipfs_pinning_facility.stats_user_daily_counters
      WHERE type <> 'shares_viewed_by_others'
      ) activity_ids_dates
    WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 from all_users WHERE id = user_id)
    GROUP BY week_start
), preprocessed AS (
    SELECT
        week_start,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
            FROM all_users
            WHERE registered_at < week_start
                AND (deleted_at IS NULL OR deleted_at > week_start)
        ) AS actual_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
            FROM all_users
            WHERE deleted_at < week_start + '1 week'::INTERVAL
        ) AS cumulative_churned_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
            FROM all_users
            WHERE registered_at >= week_start
                AND registered_at < week_start + '1 week'::INTERVAL
        ) AS weekly_new_users,
        (
            SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT id)
            FROM all_users
            WHERE deleted_at >= week_start
                AND deleted_at < week_start + '1 week'::INTERVAL
        ) AS weekly_churned_users,
        COALESCE(weekly_active_users, 0) AS weekly_active_users
    FROM datetable dt
    LEFT JOIN weekly_activity USING (week_start)
    ORDER BY week_start DESC
)
SELECT
    week_start AS for_week_of, 
    actual_users + cumulative_churned_users AS cumulative_users,
    cumulative_churned_users,
    cumulative_churned_users::FLOAT / NULLIF((actual_users + cumulative_churned_users)::FLOAT, 0) AS cumulated_churn_rate,
    actual_users,
    weekly_new_users,
    weekly_churned_users,
    weekly_active_users,
    weekly_churned_users::FLOAT / NULLIF(actual_users::FLOAT, 0) AS weekly_churn_rate 
FROM preprocessed;
```

Results of query analysis:

```
QUERY PLAN
Subquery Scan on preprocessed  (cost=40875.45..7501783.95 rows=1000 width=68) (actual time=1553.471..13613.116 rows=231 loops=1)
  Output: preprocessed.week_start, (preprocessed.actual_users + preprocessed.cumulative_churned_users), preprocessed.cumulative_churned_users, ((preprocessed.cumulative_churned_users)::double precision / NULLIF(((preprocessed.actual_users + preprocessed.cumulative_churned_users))::double precision, '0'::double precision)), preprocessed.actual_users, preprocessed.weekly_new_users, preprocessed.weekly_churned_users, preprocessed.weekly_active_users, ((preprocessed.weekly_churned_users)::double precision / NULLIF((preprocessed.actual_users)::double precision, '0'::double precision))
  Buffers: shared hit=287734 read=1964, temp read=274840 written=873
  CTE all_users
    ->  Append  (cost=0.00..30953.99 rows=70293 width=32) (actual time=0.099..1313.372 rows=71228 loops=1)
          Buffers: shared hit=285995 read=1964
          ->  Seq Scan on org_accounts.users  (cost=0.00..27912.65 rows=70009 width=32) (actual time=0.099..1289.469 rows=70007 loops=1)
                Output: users.id, users.registered_at, NULL::timestamp with time zone
                Filter: ((users.email !~~ '%@mailinator%'::text) AND (users.email !~~ '%@org%'::text) AND (users.email !~~ '%testaccnt%'::text) AND (users.status = 'active'::text) AND ((org_accounts.__user_is_qa(users.id))::text <> 'Y'::text))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 9933
                Buffers: shared hit=285269 read=1964
          ->  Seq Scan on org_accounts.deleted_users  (cost=0.00..1986.94 rows=284 width=32) (actual time=0.014..14.267 rows=1221 loops=1)
                Output: deleted_users.id, deleted_users.created_at, deleted_users.deleted_at
                Filter: ((deleted_users.email !~~ '%@mailinator%'::text) AND (deleted_users.email !~~ '%@org%'::text) AND (deleted_users.email !~~ '%testaccnt%'::text) AND (deleted_users.deleter_id = deleted_users.id))
                Rows Removed by Filter: 61826
                Buffers: shared hit=726
  ->  Merge Left Join  (cost=9921.47..7470794.97 rows=1000 width=44) (actual time=1553.467..13612.496 rows=231 loops=1)
        Output: (((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date), (SubPlan 2), (SubPlan 3), (SubPlan 4), (SubPlan 5), COALESCE(weekly_activity.weekly_active_users, '0'::bigint)
        Inner Unique: true
        Merge Cond: ((((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date) = weekly_activity.week_start)
        Buffers: shared hit=287734 read=1964, temp read=274840 written=873
        ->  Sort  (cost=1601.45..1603.95 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=10.108..10.250 rows=231 loops=1)
              Output: (((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date)
              Sort Key: (((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date) DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 35kB
              Buffers: shared hit=726
              ->  Result  (cost=1514.10..1541.62 rows=1000 width=4) (actual time=9.986..10.069 rows=231 loops=1)
                    Output: ((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date
                    Buffers: shared hit=726
                    InitPlan 6 (returns $5)
                      ->  Aggregate  (cost=1514.09..1514.10 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=9.974..9.975 rows=1 loops=1)
                            Output: min(deleted_users_1.created_at)
                            Buffers: shared hit=726
                            ->  Seq Scan on org_accounts.deleted_users deleted_users_1  (cost=0.00..1356.47 rows=63047 width=8) (actual time=0.006..4.332 rows=63047 loops=1)
                                  Output: deleted_users_1.id, deleted_users_1.email, deleted_users_1.created_at, deleted_users_1.deleter_id, deleted_users_1.deleted_at, deleted_users_1.registration_app
                                  Buffers: shared hit=726
                    ->  ProjectSet  (cost=0.00..5.03 rows=1000 width=8) (actual time=9.984..10.030 rows=231 loops=1)
                          Output: generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)
                          Buffers: shared hit=726
                          ->  Result  (cost=0.00..0.01 rows=1 width=0) (actual time=0.000..0.001 rows=1 loops=1)
        ->  Sort  (cost=8320.02..8320.52 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=1475.315..1475.418 rows=159 loops=1)
              Output: weekly_activity.weekly_active_users, weekly_activity.week_start
              Sort Key: weekly_activity.week_start DESC
              Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 32kB
              Buffers: shared hit=287008 read=1964, temp read=412 written=872
              ->  Subquery Scan on weekly_activity  (cost=8050.90..8312.37 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=1466.686..1475.279 rows=159 loops=1)
                    Output: weekly_activity.weekly_active_users, weekly_activity.week_start
                    Buffers: shared hit=287008 read=1964, temp read=412 written=872
                    ->  GroupAggregate  (cost=8050.90..8310.37 rows=200 width=12) (actual time=1466.685..1475.254 rows=159 loops=1)
                          Output: ((date_trunc('week'::text, ("*SELECT* 1".date)::timestamp with time zone))::date), count(DISTINCT "*SELECT* 1".user_id)
                          Group Key: ((date_trunc('week'::text, ("*SELECT* 1".date)::timestamp with time zone))::date)
                          Buffers: shared hit=287008 read=1964, temp read=412 written=872
                          ->  Sort  (cost=8050.90..8136.22 rows=34130 width=20) (actual time=1466.668..1468.872 rows=23005 loops=1)
                                Output: ((date_trunc('week'::text, ("*SELECT* 1".date)::timestamp with time zone))::date), "*SELECT* 1".user_id
                                Sort Key: ((date_trunc('week'::text, ("*SELECT* 1".date)::timestamp with time zone))::date)
                                Sort Method: quicksort  Memory: 2566kB
                                Buffers: shared hit=287008 read=1964, temp read=412 written=872
                                ->  Hash Join  (cost=1586.09..5481.12 rows=34130 width=20) (actual time=1411.350..1462.022 rows=23005 loops=1)
                                      Output: (date_trunc('week'::text, ("*SELECT* 1".date)::timestamp with time zone))::date, "*SELECT* 1".user_id
                                      Inner Unique: true
                                      Hash Cond: ("*SELECT* 1".user_id = all_users.id)
                                      Buffers: shared hit=287008 read=1964, temp read=412 written=872
                                      ->  Append  (cost=0.00..3080.17 rows=68261 width=20) (actual time=0.010..25.441 rows=68179 loops=1)
                                            Buffers: shared hit=1013
                                            ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 1"  (cost=0.00..1018.43 rows=21568 width=20) (actual time=0.008..7.895 rows=21532 loops=1)
                                                  Output: "*SELECT* 1".date, "*SELECT* 1".user_id
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=372
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on org_storage_extra.stats_user_daily_counters  (cost=0.00..802.75 rows=21568 width=20) (actual time=0.008..5.910 rows=21532 loops=1)
                                                        Output: stats_user_daily_counters.user_id, stats_user_daily_counters.date
                                                        Filter: (stats_user_daily_counters.type = ANY ('{created_file,created_folder,created_secure_fetch}'::text[]))
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 9795
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=372
                                            ->  Subquery Scan on "*SELECT* 2"  (cost=0.00..1720.44 rows=46693 width=20) (actual time=0.009..12.460 rows=46647 loops=1)
                                                  Output: "*SELECT* 2".date, "*SELECT* 2".user_id
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=641
                                                  ->  Seq Scan on ipfs_pinning_facility.stats_user_daily_counters stats_user_daily_counters_1  (cost=0.00..1253.51 rows=46693 width=20) (actual time=0.009..8.209 rows=46647 loops=1)
                                                        Output: stats_user_daily_counters_1.user_id, stats_user_daily_counters_1.date
                                                        Filter: (stats_user_daily_counters_1.type <> 'shares_viewed_by_others'::text)
                                                        Rows Removed by Filter: 2354
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=641
                                      ->  Hash  (cost=1583.59..1583.59 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=1411.250..1411.251 rows=71228 loops=1)
                                            Output: all_users.id
                                            Buckets: 131072 (originally 1024)  Batches: 2 (originally 1)  Memory Usage: 3073kB
                                            Buffers: shared hit=285995 read=1964, temp read=100 written=717
                                            ->  HashAggregate  (cost=1581.59..1583.59 rows=200 width=16) (actual time=1383.986..1398.270 rows=71228 loops=1)
                                                  Output: all_users.id
                                                  Group Key: all_users.id
                                                  Batches: 5  Memory Usage: 4161kB  Disk Usage: 1544kB
                                                  Buffers: shared hit=285995 read=1964, temp read=100 written=560
                                                  ->  CTE Scan on all_users  (cost=0.00..1405.86 rows=70293 width=16) (actual time=0.102..1351.241 rows=71228 loops=1)
                                                        Output: all_users.id
                                                        Buffers: shared hit=285995 read=1964, temp written=296
        SubPlan 2
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=1777.05..1777.06 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=20.197..20.197 rows=1 loops=231)
                Output: count(DISTINCT all_users_1.id)
                Buffers: temp read=68607 written=1
                ->  CTE Scan on all_users all_users_1  (cost=0.00..1757.33 rows=7888 width=16) (actual time=0.883..10.874 rows=27239 loops=231)
                      Output: all_users_1.id, all_users_1.registered_at, all_users_1.deleted_at
                      Filter: ((all_users_1.registered_at < (((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date)) AND ((all_users_1.deleted_at IS NULL) OR (all_users_1.deleted_at > (((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date))))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 43989
                      Buffers: temp read=68607 written=1
        SubPlan 3
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=1815.90..1815.91 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=11.215..11.215 rows=1 loops=231)
                Output: count(DISTINCT all_users_2.id)
                Buffers: temp read=68607
                ->  CTE Scan on all_users all_users_2  (cost=0.00..1757.33 rows=23431 width=16) (actual time=11.009..11.150 rows=231 loops=231)
                      Output: all_users_2.id, all_users_2.registered_at, all_users_2.deleted_at
                      Filter: (all_users_2.deleted_at < ((((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date) + '7 days'::interval))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 70997
                      Buffers: temp read=68607
        SubPlan 4
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=1933.94..1933.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=14.515..14.515 rows=1 loops=231)
                Output: count(DISTINCT all_users_3.id)
                Buffers: temp read=68607
                ->  CTE Scan on all_users all_users_3  (cost=0.00..1933.06 rows=351 width=16) (actual time=2.264..14.424 rows=308 loops=231)
                      Output: all_users_3.id, all_users_3.registered_at, all_users_3.deleted_at
                      Filter: ((all_users_3.registered_at >= (((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date)) AND (all_users_3.registered_at < ((((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date) + '7 days'::interval)))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 70920
                      Buffers: temp read=68607
        SubPlan 5
          ->  Aggregate  (cost=1933.94..1933.95 rows=1 width=8) (actual time=6.556..6.556 rows=1 loops=231)
                Output: count(DISTINCT all_users_4.id)
                Buffers: temp read=68607
                ->  CTE Scan on all_users all_users_4  (cost=0.00..1933.06 rows=351 width=16) (actual time=6.441..6.547 rows=5 loops=231)
                      Output: all_users_4.id, all_users_4.registered_at, all_users_4.deleted_at
                      Filter: ((all_users_4.deleted_at >= (((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date)) AND (all_users_4.deleted_at < ((((generate_series(date_trunc('week'::text, $5), date_trunc('week'::text, now()), '7 days'::interval)))::date) + '7 days'::interval)))
                      Rows Removed by Filter: 71223
                      Buffers: temp read=68607
Planning Time: 0.612 ms
Execution Time: 13615.054 ms
```

Comment: Is there s problem? And could you please share the results from explain (analyze, verbose, buffers) for this statement, in plain text. The ddl for the tables and indexes involved would be handy as well

Comment: @FrankHeikens I've updated the query to include the analysis.
For indexes, I'm not sure there are any. Seems to be just a record "for every combination of (date, user, ...)" if that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An obvious optimization is to eliminate redundant table scans. There isn't any need in `preprocessed` to query from `all_users` more than once. The following query uses `COUNT` with `FILTER` to gather the same statistics:

```
WITH datetable AS (SELECT GENERATE_SERIES(
                            DATE_TRUNC('week', (SELECT MIN(created_at) FROM org_accounts.deleted_users)),
                            DATE_TRUNC('week', NOW()),
                            '1 week'::INTERVAL
                            )::DATE AS week_start),
     all_users AS (SELECT id,
                          registered_at,
                          NULL AS deleted_at
                     FROM org_accounts.users
                     WHERE status = 'active'
                       AND org_accounts.__user_is_qa(id) <> 'Y'
                       AND email NOT LIKE '%@org%'
                   UNION ALL
                   SELECT id,
                          created_at AS registered_at,
                          deleted_at
                     FROM org_accounts.deleted_users
                     WHERE deleter_id = id
                       AND email NOT LIKE '%@org%'),
     weekly_activity AS (SELECT DATE_TRUNC('week', date)::DATE AS week_start,
                                COUNT(DISTINCT user_id)        AS weekly_active_users
                           FROM (SELECT user_id, date
                                   FROM org_storage_extra.stats_user_daily_counters
                                   WHERE type IN ('created_file', 'created_folder', 'created_secure_fetch')
                                 UNION ALL
                                 SELECT user_id, date
                                   FROM ipfs_pinning_facility.stats_user_daily_counters
                                   WHERE type <> 'shares_viewed_by_others') activity_ids_dates
                           WHERE EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM all_users WHERE id = user_id)
                           GROUP BY week_start),
     preprocessed AS (SELECT week_start,
                             us.actual_users,
                             us.cumulative_churned_users,
                             us.weekly_new_users,
                             us.weekly_churned_users,
                             COALESCE(weekly_active_users, 0) AS weekly_active_users
                        FROM datetable dt
                          CROSS JOIN LATERAL (SELECT
                                                 COUNT(DISTINCT u.id) FILTER (WHERE u.registered_at < dt.week_start AND
                                                                                    (u.deleted_at IS NULL OR u.deleted_at > dt.week_start)) AS actual_users,
                                                 COUNT(DISTINCT u.id)
                                                 FILTER (WHERE u.deleted_at < dt.week_start + '1 week'::INTERVAL)                           AS cumulative_churned_users,
                                                 COUNT(DISTINCT u.id)
                                                 FILTER (WHERE u.registered_at >= dt.week_start AND u.registered_at <
                                                                                                    dt.week_start +
                                                                                                    '1 week'::INTERVAL)                     AS weekly_new_users,
                                                 COUNT(DISTINCT u.id)
                                                 FILTER (WHERE u.deleted_at >= dt.week_start AND u.deleted_at <
                                                                                                 dt.week_start +
                                                                                                 '1 week'::INTERVAL)                        AS weekly_churned_users
                                               FROM all_users u
                                               WHERE u.registered_at < dt.week_start + '1 week'::INTERVAL
                                                  OR (u.deleted_at >= dt.week_start AND
                                                      u.deleted_at < dt.week_start + '1 week'::INTERVAL)) us
                          LEFT JOIN weekly_activity
                                    USING (week_start)
  ORDER BY week_start DESC)
SELECT week_start                                                   AS for_week_of,
       actual_users + cumulative_churned_users                      AS cumulative_users,
       cumulative_churned_users,
       cumulative_churned_users::FLOAT /
       NULLIF((actual_users + cumulative_churned_users)::FLOAT, 0)  AS cumulated_churn_rate,
       actual_users,
       weekly_new_users,
       weekly_churned_users,
       weekly_active_users,
       weekly_churned_users::FLOAT / NULLIF(actual_users::FLOAT, 0) AS weekly_churn_rate
  FROM preprocessed;
```

There are probably other optimizations possible, but this one was immediately evident.

Comment: Hey @JohnH. Sadly this cant work. Your version of `preprocessed` references column`id` from `weekly_activity` but we aggregate that column away after grouping by `week_start`.. Edit: Some other references that dont work too, inside preprocessed.

Comment: I've revised the query to use a lateral join. I hope this attempt doesn't have a defect. Your original query implicitly performed a lateral join for each subquery against `all_users`. This approach consolidates those four subqueries into a single one. It'll be interesting to see how this performs against your live data.